# correct technical term for this pattern

Tags: design-patterns

sometimes I use a pattern which is very similar to the singleton pattern:
There is one default instance which and a static get method to aces it.

**But** you may create other instances and pass it as optional parameter and if you want to and you can even replace the default instance with a instance from a child class.

So it is **NO SINGLETON** at all but it is used like one singleton in most cases.

Anyone got an idea who to call something like this ?

Maybe half*** singleton? domiton?

Comment: Sounds like more of an *anti* pattern

Comment: I am well aware of it. But sometimes it makes sense to use a anti pattern. Passing culture specific information, and localized string libraries at every constructor call adds a lot of unnecessary complicity. Having a default culture and resource library that can be overridden makes the code a lot more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

The Global Mutable State anti-pattern?

Seriously, [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) and DI Container libraries solved the problem of lifetime management a long time ago. They will make your life (and your tests) easier.